# easy_install install Trac 0.11, but I want 0.12

Tags: linux, debian, easy-install, trac

I run the following on Debian:

```
(#:~)- easy_install Trac
Searching for Trac
Best match: Trac 0.11.1
Adding Trac 0.11.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing trac-admin script to /usr/bin
Installing tracd script to /usr/bin

Using /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for Trac
Finished processing dependencies for Trac
(root@sd-11202)(227/pts/1)(11:50:05/01/11)-
```

However if I wanted the Trac 0.12 version, how can I request this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easy_install "Trac>0.11.1"` and

`easy_install "Trac==0.12"` should not request a package smaller than version specified (case 8) or equal to versions not specfied (case 20)

Comment: Miracoulos ! Thanks ! Planty Alleluya ! Greats !

Comment: @istao glad to help :)