# There is Trac, there is Babel, but I don't see "language"

Tags: linux, debian, easy-install, trac

I've installed on a Debian system Trac 0.12 (thanks to [easy_install install Trac 0.11, but I want 0.12](https://superuser.com/questions/277674/easy-install-install-trac-0-11-but-i-want-0-12) ) and know I want to get the localization (for French).

So I've installed Babel, but that doesn't work. I've uninstalled and re-installed Trac, but that doesn't work: I don't see "Language" in the preference panel.

I do the same thing on a mandriva system, and that works like a charm.

What's happend? How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have Babel installed *before* installing Trac. Only this way you enable the i18n-related functions.

Btw, Trac 0.12 is the first version with translated web-UI, with 0.11 and before you'd never see it, because it's simply not there.